# How can I tell if a client connected to hostapd is using 802.11ax?

Tags: wifi, hostapd

I am using hostapd version 2.10.  I know how to do this from the station side in some cases, but what I want to do is decipher the information on the access point side.  One possible solution would be to use hostapd_cli, but I can't find any documentation for the output.

When I run **hostapd_cli all_sta** I see:

```
00:1a:ef:58:2a:bb
flags=[AUTH][ASSOC][AUTHORIZED][WMM][MFP][HT]
aid=1
capability=0x11
listen_interval=5
supported_rates=0c 12 18 24 30 48 60 6c
timeout_next=NULLFUNC POLL
dot11RSNAStatsSTAAddress=00:1a:ef:58:2a:bb
dot11RSNAStatsVersion=1
dot11RSNAStatsSelectedPairwiseCipher=00-0f-ac-4
dot11RSNAStatsTKIPLocalMICFailures=0
dot11RSNAStatsTKIPRemoteMICFailures=0
wpa=2
AKMSuiteSelector=00-0f-ac-8
hostapdWPAPTKState=11
hostapdWPAPTKGroupState=0
rx_packets=65
tx_packets=2
rx_bytes=11248
tx_bytes=631
inactive_msec=0
signal=-38
rx_rate_info=0
tx_rate_info=0
ht_mcs_bitmask=ffff0000010000000000
connected_time=139
sae_group=19
sae_rejected_groups=
```

With **wpa_cli** this is clearer, as it says:

```
wifi_generation=4
```

or

```
wifi_generation=6
```

Comment: I am not sure, until I get a working WiFi 5 (802.11ac) and working WiFi 6 (802.11ax) but I am thinking this might be the clue:

`flags=[AUTH][ASSOC][AUTHORIZED][WMM][MFP][HT]`

HT is 802.11n or WiFi 4.  So I think it is possible the flags parameter is telling me which standard the WiFi connection is using.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have a WiFi 6 client (Windows) that can log into hostapd.

In the response to **hostapd_cli all_sta** I see for WiFi 6:

```
flags=[AUTH][ASSOC][AUTHORIZED][WMM][MFP][HT][VHT][HE]
```

While for a WiFi 4 client I see:

```
flags=[AUTH][ASSOC][AUTHORIZED][WMM][MFP][HT]
```

So a flag of [HE] indicates WiFi 6.